# How to hide the URL to be shown

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working on a protocol handler for Firefox and I call the resource like that:

```
var ioservice = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                    .getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
var uri = ioservice.newURI('http://someurl'+someparams, null, null);
```

The question is that I want the user to see my protocol handler - like `protocol:params` instead of the real URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `nsIProtocolHandler.newChannel()` implementation returns a regular HTTP channel - and it is associated with an HTTP URL rather than yours. This is easy to fix however, set `channel.originalURI` to your URL (the one your got as parameter to `newChannel()`).

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIChannel#Attributes